# How to ignore rows with a mask when using str.contains?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of store names that I have to standardize. For example McDonalds 1234 LA -> McDonalds. You can see below that **Popeyes** and **Wallmart** have already been standardized:

```
   id              store  standard
0   1          McDonalds       NaN
1   2               Lidl       NaN
2   3  Lidl New York 123       NaN
3   4                KFC       NaN
4   5      Slidling Shop       NaN
5   6        Lidi Berlin       NaN
6   7         Popeyes NY   Popeyes
7   8  Wallmart LA 90210  Wallmart
8   9               Aldi       NaN
9  10        London Lidl       NaN
```

I use `str.contains` to find the store name, and place the standardized name into the `standard` column. Here I am standardizing **Lidl** stores:

```
df.loc[df.store.str.contains(r'\blidl\b', case=False), 'standard'] = 'Lidl'

print(df)

   id              store  standard
0   1          McDonalds       NaN
1   2               Lidl      Lidl
2   3  Lidl New York 123      Lidl
3   4                KFC       NaN
4   5      Slidling Shop       NaN
5   6        Lidi Berlin       NaN
6   7         Popeyes NY   Popeyes
7   8  Wallmart LA 90210  Wallmart
8   9               Aldi       NaN
9  10        London Lidl      Lidl
```

However the problem here is that it is searching `str.contains` on rows that have already been standardized (Popeyes and Wallmart).

How can I run `str.contains` only on rows where `df['standard'] == NaN` and ignore the standardized rows?

I have tried something very very messy, and it doesn't seem to work. I set a mask and then use that before running `str.contains`:

```
mask = df['standard'].isna()

df[mask].loc[df[mask].store.str.contains(aldi_regex,na=False), 'standard3'] = 'Aldi'
```

Does not work. I have also tried something even more messy and it didn't work:

```
df.loc[mask].loc[df.loc[mask].store.str.contains(aldi_regex,na=False), 'standard3'] = 'Aldi'
```

How can I ignore the standardized rows? Without resorting to a for loop.

My example dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],dtype='int64',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=10, step=1)), 'store': pd.Series(['McDonalds', 'Lidl', 'Lidl New York 123', 'KFC', 'Slidling Shop', 'Lidi Berlin', 'Popeyes NY', 'Wallmart LA 90210', 'Aldi', 'London Lidl'],dtype='object',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=10, step=1)), 'standard': pd.Series([pd.np.nan, pd.np.nan, pd.np.nan, pd.np.nan, pd.np.nan, pd.np.nan, 'Popeyes', 'Wallmart', pd.np.nan, pd.np.nan],dtype='object',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=10, step=1))}, index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=10, step=1))
```

Comment: can you try `df['standard'].mask(df['standard'].isna(),df['store'].str.extract(r'(?i)(\blidl\b)',expand=False))` ?

Comment: while I'm sure one of the superstars might give you a one liner, I think this is fairly simple to achieve with an auxiliary column (or even a list) that keeps track of the processed names

Comment: Have you tried to filter first the NaN values? `df.loc[df['standard'].notnull() & df.store.str.contains(r'\blidl\b', case=False), 'standard'] = 'Lidl'`

Comment: @anky_91 while that seems to work I'd rather not extract the values, some of them are very messy like mCdoNalDs. I just want to check if the string is there.

Comment: @hichame.yessou yes I think this works. I just needed to change it to `df.loc[df['standard'].isnull()` not `notnull()`. :)

Comment: @SCool in that case hichame.yessou sol looks fine :)

Comment: @anky_91 at least I learned something. Never heard of that `.mask()` function, I better look it up.

Comment: @SCool right! :')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I ignore the standardized rows? Without resorting to a for
>   loop.

By filtering checking for null values:

```
df.loc[df['standard'].isnull() & df.store.str.contains(r'\blidl\b', case=False), 'standard'] = 'Lidl'
```